# MS Teams Bot Framework Auto-Suggestion

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

Is there any way we can implement an auto-suggestion feature using MS Teams bot framework? The way I want this to be implemented like if someone starts typing a question to the bot on MS Teams , I want the Bot to guess the question and show it in a list below the typing area. Any suggestion or feedback or alternative approach is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Teams doesn't invoke a call to bot on keystroke from an adaptive card form.  Alternatively, you can use `InputChoiceSet`. You have to bind the question list into an `InputChoiceSet` and use it as a field inside a submission form. This way, when the user starts typing teams won't invoke a call to the backend, instead it will search on the prebuild list.